# Importing CSV to SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, csv

I exported a CSV from a SQLite database that I need to import in to SQL Server 2016 using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard.

I am having a problem with a date column that for some reason was stored as a `TEXT` column type in SQLite but in SQL Server I created it with the `date` data type.

I have chosen to convert that column from `[DT_STR]` to `[DT_DBDATE]` in SQL Server Import and Export Wizard (unsure as to whether this is actually correct or not as I don't quite understand but it seemed to make sense to me as I am converting `TEXT` to `date`.

Here are the conversion steps that it shows:

```
[Source Information]
Table: C:\Users\administrator.domain\Desktop\export.csv
Column: Column 9
Column Type: string [DT_STR]
SSIS Type: string [DT_STR]
Mapping file (to SSIS type): 

[Destination Information]
Destination Location : server\SQLEXPRESS
Destination Provider : SQLNCLI11
Table: [dbo].[cn]
Column: Column 9
Column Type: date
SSIS Type: database date [DT_DBDATE]
Mapping file (to SSIS type): C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\MappingFiles\MSSQLToSSIS10.XML

[Conversion Steps]
Step 1: DT_STR to DT_DBDATE
SSIS conversion file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\binn\DtwTypeConversion.xml
```

Here is the warning that it shows at the end of the process:

```
- Executing (Error)
Messages
Error 0xc02020c5: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed while converting column "Column 9" (46) to column "Column 9" (85).  The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Data Conversion 0 - 0.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[Column 9]" failed because error code 0xC020907F occurred, and the error row disposition on "Data Conversion 0 - 0.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[Column 9]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Data Conversion 0 - 0" (77) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Data Conversion Input" (78). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc02020c4: Data Flow Task 1: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Source - export_csv returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

Column 9 data example: `2015-04-08`

Please can someone help in where I am going wrong?

I increased the size of `[DT_STR]` to 255.

New error message:

```
- Executing (Error)
Messages
Error 0xc02020c5: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed while converting column "Column 9" (46) to column "Column 9" (85).  The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Data Conversion 0 - 0.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[Column 9]" failed because error code 0xC020907F occurred, and the error row disposition on "Data Conversion 0 - 0.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[Column 9]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

Comment: What does it say in the warning? Could you share a screenshot?

Comment: @AlokGupta Apologies, pasted the wrong one originally. I've added it now.

Comment: This is happening because length of DT_STR is more than DT_DBDATE. There should be some advance setting around DT_STR. You need to modify size of DT_STR. That's all

Comment: @Jack : possible to share file ?